# Spring data - webflux - Chaining requests

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-reactive

i use reactive Mongo Drivers and Web Flux dependancies

I have a code like below.

```
  public Mono<Employee> editEmployee(EmployeeEditRequest employeeEditRequest) {
        return employeeRepository.findById(employeeEditRequest.getId())
                .map(employee -> {
                    BeanUtils.copyProperties(employeeEditRequest, employee);
                    return employeeRepository.save(employee) 
                })
    }
```

Employee Repository has the following code

```
Mono<Employee> findById(String employeeId)
```

1. Does the thread actually block when findById is called? I understand the portion within map actually blocks the thread.
2. if it blocks, how can I make this code completely reactive?
3. Also, in this reactive paradigm of writing code, how do I handle that given employee is not found?

Comment: Please, check my solution in the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67731362/how-to-chaining-responses-from-different-services-in-order-to-create-a-flux-res?noredirect=1#comment119825831_67731362

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, **map is a blocking and synchronous operation** for which time taken is always going to be deterministic.

**Map should be used when you want to do the transformation of an object** /data in fixed time. The operations which are done synchronously. eg your BeanUtils copy properties operation.

**FlatMap should be used for non-blocking operations**, or in short anything which returns back Mono,Flux.

"how do I handle that given employee is not found?" -
findById returns empty mono when not found. So we can use switchIfEmpty here.

Now let's come to what changes you can make to your code:

```
  public Mono<Employee> editEmployee(EmployeeEditRequest employeeEditRequest) {
    
    return employeeRepository.findById(employeeEditRequest.getId())
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> {
          //do something
        }))
        .map(employee -> {
          BeanUtils.copyProperties(employeeEditRequest, employee);
          return employee;
        })
        .flatMap(employee -> employeeRepository.save(employee));

  }
```